# Unable to print Unicode char despite reading as UTF-8

Tags: python, windows, file-io, python-unicode, unicode-escapes

I am reading in file as follows:

```
def main(src):
    with open(src, encoding='UTF-8') as incoming:
        for line in incoming:
            data = line
            print(data)
        del line
```

Code gets struck at this line (I don't know if it will show in browser):

```
    <DT><A HREF="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ygKS7WU4YU" ADD_DATE="1421587655">?*** EarAbuse ♛ &#39;Pppppp&#39; (Official &amp; Uncensored) - YouTube</A>
```

Notice that **B**lack **C**hess **Q**ueen (i.e. \u265b) just after the words `EarAbuse` seems to be causing the problem as reported in-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 18, in <module>
    moduleName.main(fileName)
  File "C:\Users\Systems\Desktop\merc\bm\chrome.py", line 53, in main
    print(data)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u265b' in position
87: character maps to <undefined>
```

I have-

1. read docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html
2. used `data = repr(line)`
3. used `errors="surrogateescape"` while opening file

No love. Also charbase says that python escape for that BCQ is `u'\u265b'`, what does it mean & am I not implementing it already?

**Edit:** Strangely, typing `print('\u265b')` or `print(♛)` in IDLE works fine without any error & shows that *beautiful* BCQ - so what is wrong, why won't my code read beyond this line?

Comment: This is not a problem with the file.  It is a problem with the terminal you are trying to `print()` to.  Your terminal is using the `charmap` codec, probably because you're on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occurs when you are trying to print the BCQ character. I would guess that your console encoding/locale is not capable of emitting all Unicode code points - i.e. it is either ASCII or a 256-character codepage.

Instead of printing, try:

```
import sys

sys.stdout.buffer.write(data.encode('utf8'))
```

Comment: Of course, this will probably give you [mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) on a terminal which is not actually using UTF-8...

Comment: True - just trying to point the OP in the right direction without knowing exactly what environment the person is working in.

Comment: Thanks @user5402, support or no support my code needed something to display on the terminal - this fixed my problem. Also, please suggest a better title for this question so it may help others in future

Comment: Perhaps "Unable to print Unicode char despite reading as UTF-8" because printing is really where your program failed.

Answer (score 3):

The error is (almost) self explainatory. It says that Python tries to encode the string in Windows 1252 character set, that cannot represent `'\u265b'`. It works fine in idle, because idle is a GUI application is only limited by the glyphs that the font can represent, whereas a console application con only display the 256 characters of the code page of the console.

You should explicitely convert the string into a byte array in the correct code page, with `errors='replace'` :

```
for line in incoming:
    data = line
    print(data.encode('cp1252', errors='replace'))
```

Of course it will display a `?` instead of the `♛` as the console driver cannot display that UTF character, but you won't get any error.

If you do not like the `b'...'` saying that you are printing 8 bits characters, just convert back to string again :

```
    print(data.encode('cp1252', errors='replace').decode('cp1252'))
```

The forward-reverse encoding just ensures that all characters are now printable on the console (or are replaced).

Comment: thanks for the great insights, +1(ed), I will surely learn from your answer but will need some time being able to completely digest it. Also, how did u figure out it was `Windows 1252`?

Comment: @user4453945 : from your error message `File "...\cp1252.py"` I assumed that Python was trying to encode in win1252. But I must acknowledge I'm not really sure. But `chcp` in console shows current code page.

Comment: ok great. One more thing - how to develop good "Error Reading" prowess, if u can spare some time posting a small answer?

Comment: For Windows 8+, use `chcp 65001` to set the console to UTF-8 before starting Python. Make sure the console is using a truetype font such as Consolas. But don't use this with Windows XP, Vista, or 7. The old console server is buggy for multibyte encodings. Instead try Drekin's [win-unicode-console](https://github.com/Drekin/win-unicode-console) to use the console's native UTF-16 encoding.